# how to make scrapy just skip error and just continue?

Tags: python, scrapy

hi so id like to make scrapy just ignore a ERROR: Spider error processing error and just continue to the next iteration but this seems impossible to me. instead it just fails at this page for a certain reason and then decides its done with this funny business.

heres my script :

```
import scrapy
import jsonlines
import re

class SgbdSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "sgbd"
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.sante.gouv.sn/actualites/"
    ]
    def parse(self,response):
        try:
            base = "http://www.sante.gouv.sn"
            for link in response.css(".card-title a"):
                try:
                    title = link.css("a::text").get()
                    comNum = int(re.search("[N°][0-9]{1,3}",title,re.IGNORECASE).group(0).split("°")[-1])
                    href = link.css("a::attr(href)").extract()
                    pdfLink = base + href[0]
                    next_page = response.css("li.pager-next a::attr(href)").get()
                    if self.isInDatbase(comNum):
                        continue
                    else:
                        yield scrapy.Request(pdfLink,callback=self.extractPDF,meta = {
                            "title" : title,
                            "article" : pdfLink,
                            "page" : next_page,
                        })
                except:
                    continue
                ##  EXECUTE WITH COMMAND scrapy crawl sgbd -o pdf.jsonl -t jsonlines
                ##
                ##
                ##
                if next_page is not None and next_page.split("?page=")[-1] != "35":
                    next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
                    yield scrapy.Request(next_page,callback=self.parse)
        except print(0):
            pass
        
    def extractPDF(self,response):
        link = response.css(".file a::attr(href)").get()
        title = response.meta.get("title")
        article = response.meta.get("article")
        comNum = re.search("[N°][0-9]{1,3}",title,re.IGNORECASE)
        page = response.meta.get("page")
        date = self.getDate(title)
        day = date.get("day")
        month = date.get("month")
        year = date.get("year")
        yield {
            "link" : link,
            "title" : title,
            "article" : article,
            "page" : page,
            "comNum" : int(comNum.group(0).split("°")[-1]),
            "day" : day,
            "month" : month,
            "year" : year
            
        }
    def isInDatbase(self,com):
        found = False
        with jsonlines.open('pdf.jsonl') as f:

            for line in f.iter():
                if com == line["comNum"]:
                    found = True
                    break
            return found
    def getDay(self,text):
        day = re.search("(lundi|mardi|mercredi|mércredi|jeudi|vendredi|samedi|dimanche)",text,re.IGNORECASE)
        full = re.search("(lundi|mardi|mercredi|mércredi|jeudi|vendredi|samedi|dimanche).\d+",text,re.IGNORECASE)
        num = int(full.group(0).split(day.group(0))[-1].strip())
        return num
    def getDate(self,text):
        month = re.search("(janvier|février|fevrier|mars|avril|mai|juin|juillet|août|aout|septembre|octobre|novembre|decembre|décembre)",text,re.IGNORECASE)
        full = re.search("(janvier|février|fevrier|mars|avril|mai|juin|juillet|août|aout|septembre|octobre|novembre|decembre|décembre).\d+",text,re.IGNORECASE)
        num = int(full.group(0).split(month.group(0))[-1].strip())
        return dict(day=self.getDay(text),month=month.group(0),year=num)
```

heres the error im getting, its always the same page aswell.

```
2021-04-01 16:21:44 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://sante.sec.gouv.sn/Actualites/coronavirus-communiqu%c3%a9-de-presse-n%c2%b0389-jeudi-mars-2021-du-minist%c3%a8re-de-la-sant%c3%a9-et-de> from <GET http://www.sante.gouv.sn/Actualites/coronavirus-communiqu%C3%A9-de-presse-n%C2%B0389-jeudi-mars-2021-du-minist%C3%A8re-de-la-sant%C3%A9-et-de>
2021-04-01 16:21:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://sante.sec.gouv.sn/actualites?page=1> (referer: https://sante.sec.gouv.sn/actualites/)
2021-04-01 16:22:20 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 1 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-04-01 16:22:40 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://sante.sec.gouv.sn/Actualites/coronavirus-communiqu%c3%a9-de-presse-n%c2%b0389-jeudi-mars-2021-du-minist%c3%a8re-de-la-sant%c3%a9-et-de> (referer: None)        
2021-04-01 16:22:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://sante.sec.gouv.sn/Actualites/coronavirus-communiqu%c3%a9-de-presse-n%c2%b0389-jeudi-mars-2021-du-minist%c3%a8re-de-la-sant%c3%a9-et-de> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\dems\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 120, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "c:\users\dems\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 353, in 
__next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "c:\users\dems\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 353, in 
__next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "c:\users\dems\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in 
_evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\dems\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", 
line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "c:\users\dems\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in 
_evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\dems\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", 
line 340, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "c:\users\dems\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in 
_evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\dems\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\users\dems\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in 
_evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\dems\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\users\dems\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in 
_evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Dems\Desktop\test-scrapy\sgbd\sgbd\spiders\sgbd.py", line 46, in extractPDF
    date = self.getDate(title)
  File "C:\Users\Dems\Desktop\test-scrapy\sgbd\sgbd\spiders\sgbd.py", line 79, in getDate
    return dict(day=self.getDay(text),month=month.group(0),year=num)
  File "C:\Users\Dems\Desktop\test-scrapy\sgbd\sgbd\spiders\sgbd.py", line 73, in getDay
    num = int(full.group(0).split(day.group(0))[-1].strip())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
2021-04-01 16:22:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-04-01 16:22:41 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1404,
 'downloader/request_count': 5,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 5,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 22472,
 'downloader/response_count': 5,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 140.663172,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 1, 16, 22, 41, 148946),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 12,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 5,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 5,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 5,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 5,
 'spider_exceptions/AttributeError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 1, 16, 20, 20, 485774)}
2021-04-01 16:22:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

thank you!

Comment: Use ```with suppress```

Comment: sorry i am new to scrapy, how and where do i do that ? thanks

Comment: Put the relevant part under ```with suppress(AttributeError):```

Comment: thanks that worked, and i also found the source of the error, thank you!